# Unable to redirect when viewing static file

Tags: c#, routes

I have a `RouteMap` containing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "StaticContent",
   url: "{action}/{controller}/{type}/{content}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Admin", type="img", content="logo.png", action = "Content" }
);
```

and the handler:

```
public void Content()
{
   Response.Redirect("/Signin");
}
```

However, when I access this URL:

http://localhost:55306/Content/Admin/img/logo.png

I can still view the image.

I expect I will be redirected to the Signin page every time I access the URL above.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default route handler looks for the static asset your file is there that is why it returns the content. Please follow the following link 
[prevent access to static content of asp.net - mvc app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334427/prevent-access-to-static-content-of-asp-net-mvc-app)
this will give you some idea.

Comment: It works, one last question, in `Web.config` is it possible to have multiple selection for the path? like: `<add name="ImageFileHandler" path="(.*?)\.(png|jpeg|tiff)" ... />`?

Comment: Yes use same handler with different name. It should work.